# IBM Watson speech to test output only transcript or grep only transcript

Tags: bash, curl, scripting, grep, ibm-watson

I'm using curl with IBM Watson to produce a transcript but I can't seem to get an output where just the transcript is shown as shown below

Another method might be just to grep for the text in `transcript":""`

curl

```
 curl -u user:password -X POST --header "Content-Type: audio/wav" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" --data-binary @test.wav "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true" > demo.txt



{
   "results": [
      {
         "alternatives": [
            {
               "confidence": 0.302, 
               "transcript": "when to stop announced "
            }
         ], 
         "final": true
      }, 
      {
         "alternatives": [
            {
               "confidence": 0.724, 
               "transcript": "Russia is destroying western cheese and considering a ban Weston condoms and infection internet is reacting "
            }
         ], 
         "final": true
```

Answer (score 1):

To store the output into a file you can use the option `-o`

```
curl -u user:password -X POST --data-binary @test.wav 
-o transcript.txt
--header "Content-Type: audio/wav" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"
```

> `-o, --output <file>`
>
> Write output to <file> instead of stdout. Like in:
>
> `curl http://ibm.com.com -o "html_output.txt"`

[More info](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Answer (score 0):

`grep` alone can't do quite what you're asking for because it doesn't get more granular than a single line. However, `grep` + `sed` can - sed can be used to perform regex replacement on the lines that grep spits out.

First pipe to grep: `grep transcript`, then pipe to sed: `sed 's/.*"transcript": "\(.*\)".*/\1/g'`

Here's the complete command:

```
curl -u user:password -X POST --header "Content-Type: audio/wav" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" --data-binary @test.wav "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true" | grep transcript | sed 's/.*"transcript": "\(.*\)".*/\1/g'
```

Note that by default, curl displays several lines of status when piping it's output. You can disable those with -s:

```
curl -s -u user:password -X POST --header "Content-Type: audio/wav" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" --data-binary @test.wav "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true" | grep transcript | sed 's/.*"transcript": "\(.*\)".*/\1/g'
```

Here's more info on `sed` if you're interested: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Update: I should also mention that there are SDKs available for a number of languages if you're interested in doing something more complex - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud